# HP ThinClient ME06

Tags: windows-embedded-7, thin-client

we just purchased a HP Thinclient, I think the name was ME06 and seems to run quite well for it's size and speed, we have however one issue, every time it reboots it goes back to the original settings everytime, default user is same as username and administrator is administrator etc etc.. we wish to change this and commit the changes...

anyone have experience with this model?

I see there is a green lock down in the systray which might play a role part, but I dont know how to disable it.

Comment: That is the whole purpose of a thin client, to reset any changes made on a reboot, this is by design, only way around this is to open it up and see if there is space and a motherboard connector so you can mount a laptop hard drive, then load an OS onto that. I hacked together an old Wyse thin client a few years back like this, but it was not easy.

Comment: There should be a HP "product number" on the thin client somewhere, we need this to do further research.

Comment: I am aware that this is by design, but there should be a way to commit the changes, default user is User and Admin password is Administrator, everytime we reset, keyboard reverts to american key layout, and all other settings we need as well.. we like to have the shortcut and predefined remote desktop connection on desktop with predefined settings i.e. 2 monitors

Comment: Without a HP product number there is no way Anyone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the answer was more simple than it seemed, the client automatically logged in as a normal user, but you could logout and relogin as administrator and give this right to the normal user, change the settings you neeeded and commit the change...